# Symfony 2 server migration error

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine, migration

I have a Symfony 2 project that I have moved to a new server.

When I go to load the new website I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\AnnotationRegistry' not found in /var/www/corpsite/corpsite/app/autoload.php on line 61
```

Im very new to Symfony so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you updated you vendors?

Comment: no, how do i do that?

Comment: You need to add composer ( http://getcomposer.org/ ) to your root folder. For the rest follow the answer by @Damien

Comment: Do not run `update`! It's for version update only and should not be done on a production server (as you could get different vendors version than the developers one's!). `composer install` here. (ok you edited your comment ^^ I leave the warning anyway).

Comment: too late! I just ran update...well lets see what happens

Comment: Ok lookes like that has messed things up further. When I try to clear the cache I get the following error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle' not found in /var/www/corpsite/corpsite/app/AppKernel.php on line 14

Comment: Ok, i restored the website and did exactly what you suggested. It all seemed to work (no errors while installing composer) but I still have the same original error. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Moving a Symfony2 instance can lead to issues with the autoloading,
you should run:

```
composer.phar dump-autoload --optimize
```

(the optimize option is for PROD ONLY, and you will get a boost bonus).

Don't forgot also to clear the SF2 cache:

```
app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug

or...

rm -rf app/cache/*
```

The error can also be from non existing vendors, `composer install` is the answer then.

Comment: Thanks. I did what you suggested and it all went well, but I still have the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you check that your `vendor` directory contain a `AnnotationRegistry` class? And can you post your `app/autoload.php` file?

Comment: No it does contain an AnnotationRegistry class. Sorry I am really new to symfony....what do you mean by post to app/autoload.php? I cant edit it if thats what you mean.